# Can't use sbt 0.13.7 with Play subprojects

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a [sample Play 2.3.8 project](https://github.com/salemsaberhagen/sbt0_13_7_subprojects) that is composed by two subprojects (common and common2):

```
$ tree -L 2 .
.
├── build.sbt
├── common
│   ├── app
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── conf
├── common2
│   ├── app
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── conf
├── conf
│   (...)
├── build.sbt
```

And in the main `build.sbt` the dependency to those two subprojects is defined as:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val common2 = (project in file("common2")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val main = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
                    .aggregate(common, common2).dependsOn(common, common2)
```

and this works as expected. Now I am trying to make this project use sbt 0.13.7 (currently it uses 0.13.5) and when I start activator I always get a error like this (`Test` is the root of my project):

```
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No project 'common' in 'file:/home/user/Desktop/Test/'.
Valid project IDs: main
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    // OMITTED
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] No project 'common' in 'file:/home/user/Desktop/Test/'.
[error] Valid project IDs: main
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

So what could be the problem? Have the way to define subprojects changed? I have looked at the [changes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html) from 0.13.5 to 0.13.7 and can't find nothing related to this...

Comment: Just checking, but you've run `clean` right?

Comment: Yes I did (set sbt to 0.13.5 -> clean -> set sbt to 0.13.7). The problem is in sbt side (I can't even load the project so I can't run `update`, `compile`, etc). Also this only happens in a sub-project setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed it seems that something changed between sbt 0.13.5 and 0.13.6. In my sample project I have all the subprojects defined in the main `build.sbt`, but had also them redefined inside the subprojects folder.

So in `common/build.sbt` for example, the subproject is defined again as

```
lazy val main = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

This works well in 0.13.5, but breaks after that.

So the solution was to remove those lines and only define the subprojects in the main `build.sbt`.

Comment: I had the same issue and it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was also discussed in May 2016 here: [SBT: How to define dependencies of subprojects in subprojects' build.sbt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257130/sbt-how-to-define-dependencies-of-subprojects-in-subprojects-build-sbt-files) The answer in the comments is also basically that SBT doesn't want you to have build.sbt files in your subprojects of multiproject builds.