# Play framework: Add routes from sub-projects dynamically

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm developing a system to discover subprojects at compile time. This works. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942220/sbt-dynamic-aggregation-of-subproject). Now the only issue is that the subproject's route file is being ignored.

I know that the normal way to include a route file in the main route file is by hardcoding the latter into the former. But that would defy my goal of dynamic subprojects.

I bet that there's a way to, in Build.scala, discover a route file and append it to the main route file. But I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to do it. Could you please help me out?

Alternatively, if there's no way to do it at compile time, maybe there's a way to load it at runtime? I know there's an [api to intercept requests](https://jazzy.id.au/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html). So if we can read the routes we could implement dynamic routing that way. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i had to write fragments of the routing file (one per each sub-project, use a different extension like subproject.routes for example) and then concatenate them all together into a single routes file. You have to do this also for the application.conf file.

I did this via the Build.sbt script:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play._
import java.io._

object Build extends Build {

  val commonSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
  )

  IO.copyFile(file("conf/base.routes"), file("conf/routes"))

  IO.copyFile(file("conf/base.application.conf"), file("conf/application.conf"))

  lazy val libFolder = file("base-lib");
  lazy val baseLib = processModule(libFolder)

  lazy val modules = (file("modules") * DirectoryFilter).get.map { dir =>
    processModule(dir).dependsOn(baseLib)
  }

  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
    .settings(
      name := "mainProject",
      version := "1.0"
    )
    .dependsOn(modules map (m => m: ClasspathDependency): _*)
    .aggregate(modules map (m => m: ProjectReference): _*)

  override lazy val projects = root +: modules +: dspcloudLib

  def processModule(dir: File):Project = {
    val p = Project(dir.getName, dir).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(commonSettings: _*)

    val mf = new File(dir, "conf/" + dir.getName + ".r")
    val r = IO.read(mf)
    IO.append(file("conf/routes"), r.toString)

    val cf = new File(dir, "conf/" + dir.getName + ".application.conf")
    val c = IO.read(cf)
    IO.append(file("conf/application.conf"), c.toString)

    p
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submodules could implement their own [routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRoutingDsl). See example in [api doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/routing/RoutingDsl.html). Optionally, you could hook into `Compile` task in your root project and append all the routes to main `routes` file programmatically.

Comment: Any example on how to use the Compile task?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820939/run-custom-task-automatically-before-after-standard-task