# Can sbt dynamically use a generated subproject's build.sbt

Tags: sbt

My main project needs to generate a sub-project with its own build.sbt and then compile and use the sub-project. If the sub-project was pre-generated, I could reference it from the main build.sbt with `RootProject`. But if the sub-project is not yet generated, any attempt to use a value of `lazy val sub = RootProject(subBaseDir)` fails.

Is it possible to load the sub-project that does not exist at the moment of sbt start, so some tasks of the main project depended of the sub-project?

Comment: Note this question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942220/sbt-dynamic-aggregation-of-subproject where all sub-projects do exist at the moment of sbt start, and just need to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible in SBT 0.13.13 using its new feature called "Synthetic subprojects". You won't have a `build.sbt` file for such synthetic projects, since they're, well, completely synthetic. But otherwise they're completely functional projects, and you should be able to set up the dependencies between tasks of current project and its derived projects.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this new feature myself yet.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the synthetic subproject with a generated build.sbt later in the build steps?