# SBT: How to define dependencies of subprojects in subprojects' build.sbt files?

Tags: scala, build, sbt, multi-project, subproject

The following build.sbt file works, but it defines the dependencies of all subprojects:

```
name := "myproject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.60-R9"
)


lazy val aLib = (project in file("lib/a"))
lazy val bLib = (project in file("lib/b"))
  .dependsOn(aLib)
  .dependsOn(cLib)
lazy val cLib = (project in file("lib/c"))
  .dependsOn(aLib)
lazy val myApp = (project in file("myapp"))
  .dependsOn(aLib)
  .dependsOn(bLib)
  .dependsOn(cLib)
  .aggregate(aLib, bLib, cLib)
```

Since each subproject (directories lib/a, lib/b, lib/c, myapp) has its own build.sbt file, I would like to use those build files to define the individual dependencies of each project.

**I tried to move the `dependsOn`/`aggregate` statements to the subprojects' build files, but I am not able to make it work that way. What is the recommended way?**

Comment: the recommended way is to not have build.sbt files in subdirectories.

Comment: @DaleWijnand could you please provide a reference to sbt documentation or something else supporting your statement?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's explicit in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html but I can tell you it's the recommended case from hearing the bugs, edge cases and unsupported cases in multi, nested build.sbt files.

Comment: @DaleWijnand: "The recommended way is to not have build.sbt files in subdirectories". If I remove one of the subprojects' build.sbt files, the super project does not compile any more (because the subproject's Scala version is not defined). Hence this cannot be the recommended way...

Comment: Well the transition requires more than just removing files - you would have to migrate the contents (and thus the definition of the build) of those subprojects into the root build.sbt.